# Открыть robots.txt на nginx

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Хочу, чтобы по адресу /robots.txt отдавался файл, который я укажу с помощью относительного пути на сервере. Написал такое правило:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/robots.txt;  
}
```

Не работает, потому что ставит в конце слэш и переходит на site.ru/robots.txt/

Как сделать так, чтобы слэш не подставлялся в robots? Для всех остальных путей слэш нужен.

UPD Я уже не знаю что и думать. Вот такая конструкция работает как надо:

```
location /robotz.txt {
    alias /home/bla/bla/project/robots.txt;    
}
```

А вот такая добавляет слэш и дает 404 ошибку:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /home/bla/bla/project/robots.txt;    
 }
```

Comment: Попробуйте просто убрать robots.txt в конце алиаса. Алиас должен указывать на каталог, а не на файл

Comment: Так как вы рекомендуете не получится. Потому что это будет ссылка на папку, а не на файл в этой папке. Ниже уже советовали вариант с root. Наверное он корректнее и он даже работает. Да и alias работает. Но только если путь не robots.txt. То есть именно этот пусть чем-то перебивается. В конфигах ничего об этом нет и я не знаю что делать и куда смотреть)

Comment: Ну тогда `location ~ ^/(robots\.txt)$ { alias /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/$1; }`

Comment: `$ grep -r robots /etc/nginx` ?

Comment: В этой папке упоминаний robots.txt нет :(

Comment: 1. Вы уверены, что перед вашим nginx нет ничего, что могло бы выдавать редирект? 2. Если вы проверяете браузером, сбросьте кеш, т.к. редиректы тоже кешируются, или используйте какой-нибудь `curl`.

Comment: Невероятно, но это реально кэш. Я просто открыл в инкогнито - все работает. Но выходит, что правила для роботс.тхт кэшируются, а для других адресов - нет. Потому что на их изменения реакция происходит сразу. Вы не знаете, это можно настроить на уровне сервера?

Comment: Это не правила кешируются, а редиректы. Если ваш сервер/nginx когда-то отдавал на запрос `/robots.txt` ответ в виде `301 permanent redirect`, то по стандарту такой ответ кешируется навсегда, если в ответе не было дополнительных заголовков кеширования. Надо просто быть осторожнее с 301 и с заголовками кеширования.

Answer (score 0):

```
location = /robots.txt {
    root /home/folder1/folder2/folder3;  
}
```

Comment: Тут даже другая проблема, и я не пойму какая. Если я пишу в location /robots.txt, то добавляется слэш и ничего не работает. А если адрес другой - все работает. В конфигах роботс больше вроде нигде не упоминается. Вообще не знаю куда смотреть.